# Assigning instance field inside method

Tags: java

Look at the method setupCamera. I use it to reduce the size of the create method. As you can see, inside this method I instantiate camera and viewport, that are fields. 
Is there any problem to do that, or exists  there any surer way to do that?

```
public class HudCameraSample extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private static final float SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final float SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;
    private static final float SCENE_WIDTH = 12.8f;
    private static final float SCENE_HEIGHT = 7.2f;
    private static final float WORLD_TO_SCREEN = SCENE_HEIGHT / SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    private OrthographicCamera camera, hudCamera;
    private Viewport viewport, hudViewport;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        setupCamera(camera, viewport, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
        setupCamera(hudCamera, hudViewport, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void setupCamera(Camera camera, Viewport viewport, float width, float height) {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FillViewport(width, height, camera);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any problem to do that, or exists there any surer way to do that?

Yes, it's completely broken as in `setupCamera` you're assigning local variables and the fields remain untouched. There are no `var` parameters in Java. You'd actually need something allowing to return both camera and viewport. This is doable somehow, but too verbose for the little code you're trying to minimize.

Comment: Yes, totally. I traveled in mayonnaise...